# How to create a PHP rule with if statement and push an certain array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

How can I create a PHP if rule(s) and push a certain php array:

Let's say I have 3 numerical values that come from POST:

```
$Tanks= intval($_POST["Tanks"]);
$Fish= intval($_POST["Fish"]);
$Vegetables= intval($_POST["Vegetables"]);
```

The request is:

```
Request: Tanks -> 2; Fish -> 4; Vegetables ->1
```

And I want to create PHP IF rule(s) if the above results are met to push the below array(s):

```
array_push($tank,array("objType" => "Fish"), array("objType" => "Fish"));
array_push($tank,array("objType" => "Fish"), array("objType" => "Fish"), array("objType" => "Vegetables"));
```

An aproximate example will be ( its incorect)

```
 if ( (count($Tanks) == 2) and (count($Fish) == 4) )
 then
 array_push($tank,array("objType" => "Fish"), array("objType" => "Fish"));
    array_push($tank,array("objType" => "Fish"), array("objType" => "Fish"));
```

Examples of what i need:

- **Example 1:** If the customer requests 2 tanks and 4 fish I want to create an order for Tank1 ->  contains 2 fish and Tank2 -> contains 2 fish
- **Example 2:** If the customer requests 2 tanks and 3 fish I want to create an order for Tank1 -> contains 2 fish and Tank2 -> contain 1 fish
- **Example 3:** If the customer requests 2 tanks and 5 fish I want to create an order for Tank1 -> contains 3 fish and Tank2 -> contains 2 fish
- **Example 4:** If the customer requests 3 tanks and 6 fish I want to create an order for Tank1 -> contains 2 fish and Tank2 -> contains 2 fish and Tank3 -> contains 2 fish

...and so on.

I have spent several days with this matter and hope that the new year to bring me the answer.

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do ^^. You may have to explain it a lil bit better.

Comment: I don't understand either

Comment: I agree.  Your post is a bit vague.  I see that you are creating two tanks, but how do you figure where to put the fish and vegatables?

Comment: That it what i need to do, to create a set of rules and provide the order based on the values received from the form ( tanks, fish, vegetables )

Comment: Well we can't really tell you what those rules are.  You would know them.  That is the last piece of the puzzle (the way I understand the question) is how you determine if a fish goes to tank one or tank two.

Comment: Ok, what can these rules be? Who is the receiver? How much does he receives? Why the first tank didn't receive the vegetable?

Comment: If i get you right, you have some Tanks and there is space for 2 items in each tank and you want to fill fish and vegetables into the tanks untill they full ?

Comment: You are pushing to `$tank` both times? So why don't you do just 1 `array_push($tank,...)` instead of 2?

Comment: Those 3 values come from a html form, and are received on a order page. The first tabk did not receive vegetables because that its what i want to do ( create strict rule is some requirement are met )

Comment: I feel kind of stupid because is read your post about 20 times... and still dont have a clue what this should be that you want... for me this simply makes no sense.... sorry. Guess I will wait on some answers with some better guessers and than may provide a improved answere if its still needed.

Comment: Question is unclear and there is no real code. Please give us a real life example (but propably this is something that can be fixed with good reading of php.net arrays chapter). EDIT: Now is much clearer!

Comment: Why don't you do this with js and then send a proper json object?

Comment: Your examples offer some better insight, but they stop at two tanks.  Is there something that is preventing you from writing something that will evenly distribute fish/vegetables evenly among tanks?

Comment: No maximum tanks is 5, maximum fish is 6, and maximum vegetables is 6

Comment: jeremyb could please give me an example of how to do this with json ?

Comment: @jeremyb could please give me an example of how to do this with json ?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$tanks = 3;

$items = array(
            'fishes' => 5,
            'vegetables' => 3
);

$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $tanks; $i ++) {
    $result['tank_'+$i] = array();

    foreach ($items as $name => $value) {
            $max = floor($value/$tanks);

            if ($value % $tanks >= ($i +1)) {
                $max ++;
            }

            for ($z = 0; $z < $max; $z++) {
                $result['tank_'+$i][] = array('objType' => $name);                        
            }

    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

you just need to insert correct values to tanks and items

EDIT2: fixed a bug

Comment: In this case $value will be number of your items in $items. Foreach goes trough all items in array, takes name and value.

Comment: I get : Incorrect number of tanks in XML request (minimum: 1 tank, maximum: 5 tanks).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am french, sorry for the bad english ><

A json solution would allow your php to just receive a json object and save it, there would be no distribution to be made.

The client has some kind of pretty interface on his page, with a tank represented as a square. He adds another tank by clicking a button, a second square appears.

On the top of the page, you have 2 images, for fish and vegetables.
The user drags and drops the "elements" on the tank he wishes to.

I really don't know if this is the purpose you want your app to work for, but this would allow you, on some kind of submit button, to create a json object very simply, which would look like this:

```
var tanks = [
                {
                    'name': 'supertank'
                    'fish': [
                        {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'name': 'myFirstSuperFish'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'name': 'mySecondSuperFish'
                        }
                    ],
                    'vegetable': [
                        {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'name': 'goodPotatoe'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'name': 'supertank'
                    'fish': [
                        {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'name': 'myFirstSuperFish'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'name': 'mySecondSuperFish'
                        }
                    ],
                    'vegetable': [
                        {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'name': 'goodPotatoe'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];
```

Comment: This will work only for a 1 tank selected, But if i select 2 tanks and 4 fishs, i receive the response for 2 tanks each tank has 2 fishs,( and i dont want this because on a total the fish count is double )

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty funny question though :)

Here's small recursive function for you:

```
function putFishesToTanks(&$tankArray, $tanks, $fish) {
    $tankNumber = 0;

    for ($i=1; $i<=$tanks; $i++) {
        if (!isset($tankArray[$tankNumber])) {
            $tankArray[$tankNumber] = array();
        }

        if ($fish) {
            $tankArray[$tankNumber][] = 'fish';
            $fish--;
        }

        $tankNumber++;
    }

    if ($fish) {
        putFishesToTanks($tankArray, $tanks, $fish);
    }
}

$tanks = intval($_POST["tanks"]);
$fish = intval($_POST["fish"]);

$tankArray = array();

putFishesToTanks($tankArray, $tanks, $fish);

var_dump($tankArray);
```

Hope it helps! EDIT: Added creation of empty tanks.

Comment: is returns blank page :(

Comment: Note that I changed POST variables to lowercase. This is not copy-paste code.

Comment: I get : Incorrect number of tanks in XML request (minimum: 1 tank, maximum: 5 tanks).